# Is there any way to play the 3gpp video on Iphone?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, twilio, avplayer

I'm getting the video from the Twilio server is in 3gpp video format, and when I tried to convert that 3gpp video to mp4 then it is not converting.

For converting the video to mp4 I'm using this code.

```
func encodeVideo(videoURL: URL){
    let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL)
    let startDate = Date()
    let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: avAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)
    
    let docDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let myDocPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: docDir).appendingPathComponent("temp.mp4")?.absoluteString
    
    let docDir2 = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] as NSURL
    
    let filePath = docDir2.appendingPathComponent("rendered-Video.mp4")
    deleteFile(filePath!)
    
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: myDocPath!){
        do{
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: myDocPath!)
        }catch let error{
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    exportSession?.outputURL = filePath
    exportSession?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
    exportSession?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    
    let start = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, preferredTimescale: 0)
    let range = CMTimeRange(start: start, duration: avAsset.duration)
    exportSession?.timeRange = range
    
    exportSession!.exportAsynchronously{() -> Void in
        switch exportSession!.status{
        case .failed:
            print("\(exportSession!.error!)")
        case .cancelled:
            print("Export cancelled")
        case .completed:
            let endDate = Date()
            let time = endDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
            print(time)
            print("Successful")
            print(exportSession?.outputURL ?? "")
        default:
            break
        }
        
    }
}

func deleteFile(_ filePath:URL) {
    guard FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path) else{
        return
    }
    do {
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: filePath.path)
    }catch{
        fatalError("Unable to delete file: \(error) : \(#function).")
    }
}
```

}

While using this code I'm getting this error.

AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11838 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The operation is not supported for this media., NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped, NSUnderlyingError=0x2834f0240 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16976 "(null)"}}

Step for Conversion that I'm following:

1. First I download the video from the Twilio URL
2. Save that video in the document directory
3. and then pass the document directory video URL in the above function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `AVAssetExportSession` to convert videos to `.mp4` format, below method convert `.3gpp` format videos to `.mp4`.

Check the line `exportSession?.outputFileType = .mp4`. it specify the output format of the video.

Here `inputURL` is an url of video which needs to be converted and `outputURL` will be the final destination of video.

One more thing don't forget to specify `.mp4` extension in `outputURL` video file

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("Video.mp4").absoluteString
let outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
convertVideoToLowQuailty(withInputURL: inputUrl, outputURL: outputURL, handler: { exportSession in
    if exportSession?.status == .completed {
        // Video conversation completed
    }
})

func convertVideoToLowQuailty(withInputURL inputURL: URL?, outputURL: URL?, handler: @escaping (AVAssetExportSession?) -> Void) {
    if let anURL = outputURL {
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: anURL)
    }
    var asset: AVURLAsset? = nil
    if let anURL = inputURL {
        asset = AVURLAsset(url: anURL, options: nil)
    }
    var exportSession: AVAssetExportSession? = nil
    if let anAsset = asset {
        exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: anAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)
    }
    exportSession?.outputURL = outputURL
    exportSession?.outputFileType = .mp4
    exportSession?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
        handler(exportSession)
    })
}
```